# Conditional formatting with "and" function

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to have 2 conditions with and function in a formula for condition formatting, but without success...

Below, my code but I have an issue in formula part.

Thank for helping.

```
Columns("Y:Y").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER($J1);ISNUMBER($J2);$Y1<>$Y2)"

With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .Font.Color = RGB(174, 37, 42)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 205)
End With

Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conditional Formatting

- With `.FormatConditions.Delete` you are ensuring that the conditional formatting applied will be the only one.
- If there already is some conditional formatting and you want to **add** a new one, then you have to out-comment (delete) the line `.FormatConditions.Delete`.
- If the formatting you are trying to apply is the only one, then you could use `1` instead of `.FormatConditions.Count` (the last added CF). But why bother since the explicit numbering may only be useful when there are multiple formats.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub cfTest()

    With Columns("Y")
        .FormatConditions.Delete ' Remove any previous conditional formatting.
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER($J1);ISNUMBER($J2);$Y1<>$Y2)"
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count) ' just added CF
            .Font.Color = RGB(174, 37, 42)
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 205)
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works 